# retrieving data from snowflake as it reaches the end date of the current month

Tags: python

my boss has asked me to retrieve the data from snowflake with the help of python, for example: today is feb 12, 2024 the last date of this month is 29th  feb,2024 so i want to execute a code that will automatically download the data from snowflake as it reaches 29th feb

this is what i tried

`from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_end_of_month():

```
today = datetime.today()

end_of_month = datetime(today.year, today.month + 1, 1) - timedelta(days=1)

return end_of_month
```

end_of_month = get_end_of_month()
print("End of the month:", end_of_month)`

and i want to execute this on python

Comment: can you please make it clear that you want to execute queery in MySQL or Snowflake?

Comment: Anyway, you can use `SELECT LAST_DAY(date);`